# Rule to hide DIV if no image?

Tags: php, css, gallery

Hope you're well.

I have got the below code working as intended, but is there a way of **ONLY** showing the div 'listinggallery' if there are images returned?

At the moment, it works great if there are images in the listing, but if there are no images, then I have an empty styled div showing. Ideally I want create a rule to say "IF listingimage 'true' then show 'listinggallery'".

I have tried placing the 'listinggallery' div elsewhere within the code but just seems to crash my site, so hoping I can create a rule?

Kind regards,
Spencer

```
<div class="listinggallery">
<?php
    //Get the images ids from the post_metadata
    $images = acf_photo_gallery('gallery', $post->ID);
    //Check if return array has anything in it
    if( count($images) ):
        //Cool, we got some data so now let's loop over it
        foreach($images as $image):
            $id = $image['id']; // The attachment id of the media
            $full_image_url= $image['full_image_url']; //Full size image url
            $full_image_url = acf_photo_gallery_resize_image($full_image_url, 1024, 768); //Resized size to 262px width by 160px height image url
            $thumbnail_image_url= $image['thumbnail_image_url']; //Get the thumbnail size image url 150px by 150px
            $url= $image['url']; //Goto any link when clicked
            $target= $image['target']; //Open normal or new tab
            $alt = get_field('photo_gallery_alt', $id); //Get the alt which is a extra field (See below how to add extra fields)
            $class = get_field('photo_gallery_class', $id); //Get the class which is a extra field (See below how to add extra fields)
?>
<div class="listingimage">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <?php if( !empty($url) ){ ?><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" <?php echo ($target == 'true' )? 'target="_blank"': ''; ?>><?php } ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $full_image_url; ?>" class="fancybox">
                <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>">
            </a>
        <?php if( !empty($url) ){ ?></a><?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You could move the start tag (`<div class="listinggallery">`) inside the `if( count($images) ):` block (also don't forget to move the `</div>`)

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen I've tried moving the div code around a lot, but most of the time it just causes a critical error on my site. Could I please ask you to clarify where exactly to put the div? How do you mean put it inside the if( count($images)? Sorry my PHP knowledge is little to none. Thanks again for your help, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the creation of the `<div>` inside the block which decides if there is anything to display...

```
<?php
$images = acf_photo_gallery('gallery', $post->ID);
//Check if return array has anything in it
if( count($images) ):
    // Output start of gallery div
    ?>
    <div class="listinggallery">
    <?php
    //Cool, we got some data so now let's loop over it
    foreach($images as $image):

        // rest of code as it currently is

    endforeach; 
    // Close of gallery div
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Sir, you're a gentleman, that seems to have solved it. Thank you very much